# Any reason why these instance could be misclassified?

Tags: classification, svm, libsvm, cross-validation, predict

I started off with two files `training` & `testing`.

Then using libsvm I scaled both those files to `training.scale` and `testing.scale`

Then using `grid.py` (part of libsvm) I ran `training.scale` and and recieved some cross validation values:

```
C = 512
gamme = 0.03125
validation 5 = 66.8421
```

Then running `svm-train` using the variable found from `grid.py` and training.scale I got a new fine called `training.scale.model`

I then ran `svm-predict` and I new file called `testing.predict` and got a validation % of 60.8333%

Finally comparing `testing` and `testing.predict` found that there were 47/120 misclassifications

[https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxzgP5V6RPQHekRjZXdFYW9GX0U&usp=sharing][1]

[1]: link to code

**The real question is there any reason why these misclassification occur?**

PS. I apologise for the bad format of this question, been up for too long

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are new to machine learning. The results you've got are perfectly right.

**Reason why these mis-classifications occur?** The features you've used don't separate your classes well. A 66% cross-validation score should have given you the hint. Even by plain hit or miss method you'll get 50% accuracy, and the feature-set you used could only improve this by another 16%. Try exploring new features.

I'm assuming your data set is clean.